# How to replicate YouTubes "pull down to exit fullscreen" gesture?

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to create an app using exoplayer, and I'd like to implement a "pull down to exit fullscreen" gesture just like the youtube app has. The gesture itself seems to be doable using a gesture detector, but i don't have a ideo how to create the "pulling down and shrinking the whole video" effect.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHq7B.png)

How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this I think you can use MotionLayout. You can take a look to the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples

With MotionLayout you can have a view that can be your fullscreen video or whatever and you can animate it based on an action like the user draggin. It defines the animation in a MotionScene like this:

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/button"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#D81B60" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#9999FF" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

You can see that you can define the action as a new node like the `OnSwipe`, there you specify the direction and the touch properties. I think the documentation can help expand on all the posibilities, please take a look.